# Page footer centering using MPDF

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I have this pdf:
[image]

How can I make the page numbering centered instead of right alignment?
This is how I added the page numbering:

```
   include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");

   $mpdf=new \mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

   $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO} of {nbpg}');
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($body);

       $mpdf->Output('Packing Slip.pdf','I');
```

How can I make it center? its the 'setFooter' ?
Im am using mpdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
$mpdf->setFooter('|{PAGENO} of {nbpg}|');
```

This will center align the page numbers. Any thing on the left of first `|` will be left aligned and anything on the right of second `|` will be right alligned.

Comment: hats off. Fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can set an HTML Footer and give the proper format:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div style="text-align: center">{PAGENO} of {nbpg}</div>');
```

[SetHTMLFooter() Function](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/sethtmlfooter.html)